# Where i can find animation in .fbx?

Tags: animation, .fbx

I imported the .fbx file with animation from wowmodelviewer, but I can not find how to enable its animation in render
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you can't play it in Blender?

Comment: This model of wagon can walk and run in wowmodelviewer. Can i use this animation in Blender? the wagon rides along the purple road.